# ListView Clickable in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have displayed the Data in Listview using Jquery Mobile Selectors.My Problem is how to display Details Page when user click on listview. what i tried is to display List View is,

```
var xml;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=3175395&username=tutorialsgeek",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser});
    });
        function xmlParser(data) {
            xml = data;
            $('#load').fadeOut();
            $(xml).find("geoname").each(function () {
                var locationName = $(this).find("toponymName").text();
                var name = $(this).find("name").text(); 
                $("#list").append('<li><a href="#">locationName: '+ locationName +
                                  'name: '+ name +'</a></li>'); 
            });
            $('#list').listview('refresh');
        }
```

Here the above code will display two tag values in list for all list items.when the user Click on the List view, A New Page has to be Opened with Respective Details.

Comment: How do you open a new page? Anchor is empty in the code above.

Comment: when a first list is Clicked then i have to show first gename all tag values in new page